# Array size of 5 or higher prints output incorrectly, but size 4 or lower works perfectly

Tags: c

I'm writing a program for a class project that multiplies 2 arrays together and outputs a vector. After it multiplies the 2 arrays it also does a check to see if the 2 array inputs are equal to each other and outputs if they are or aren't.

The problem I'm having is that if the array size is 5 or higher the outputs begin to be multiplied incorrectly and I don't understand why.

**Code removed**

So an example of when its output is wrong. I execute the program and it prompts for vector size. User inputs 5. It then asks for what goes into the first array. Input is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. It asks for the second array. Input is also `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. It then computes the vectors and outputs `5, 4, 9, 16, 25` and then says the vectors are not equal. Which is incorrect.

But when it goes: Vector size 4. First input `1,2,3,4`. Second input `1, 2, 3, 4`. It outputs `1, 4, 9, 16`. Vectors are the same.

I'm very confused as to why it happens. Something must be wrong but I don't see it with my limited knowledge.

Comment: The `eq_check` variable isn’t very useful; you can simplify your function by removing it and doing `return 0;` inside the `if`, `return 1;` outside the loop.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that `n` isn’t initialized when you set the VLA sizes in `v1[n]`, `v2[n]`, and `v3[n]`. Declare on use, not at the top of the function. It’s also generally not a good idea to use VLAs sized based on user input, or really VLAs at all.

Comment: Turn up your warnings to pedantic levels, and *don't ignore them*. With warnings properly elevated `int n, v1[n]...` should produce a significant  warning note. On clang 3.8,  it would be "Variable 'n' is uninitialized when used here".

Comment: Whether VLAs are a good idea is a matter of opinion, some of us like them

Comment: `int n, v1[n]` is UB.  fix that first.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I use a VLA because I'm required to do so as per the project requirements.

Comment: `int n, v1[n],` Did you want to say "make `v1` as large as needed on the fly as value of n is changed"? There's no such thing in C. VLAs don't work this way.

Comment: Unfortunately gcc misses this even with the highest level of warning.

Comment: This is my second program I've written in C and I honestly know almost nothing about it. My programming classes have been awful at explaining how things actually work, so I'm just trying to copy the few examples I have at my disposal from the class. The value n is suppose to set all 3 arrays to the same size, none of them should change after accepting the input from the user. Once the size is determined every output should be the same size. I see people commenting that the initialization of n is out of order but this isn't something I've come by in class. If someone wouldn't mind expanding?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n)` initializes `n`. Do not attempt to declare `v1[n]` before `n` is initialized.

Comment: so if scanf("%d", &n) initializes the n, I shouldn't start with v1[n] but v1[] then let it initialize during the scanf? I'm sorry but I'm really having a hard time with all this.

Comment: @Jigbits you should move `int v1[n];` (and the other arrays) to be after the code that gives `n` a value. Things happen in order in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- The vectors must be defined **after** `n` has received the value typed by the user.  Currently, the program has undefined behavior which can cause it to behave as expected sometimes, behave in a different way some other time, or crash or whatever, regardless of what you type as input.
- The comparison function is somewhat incorrect: it should return 1 for empty vectors. It can be simplified as shown below.
- The convention for boolean values in C is `0` means false and anything else means true.  Only test if `eq_check == 0` and use an `else` clause.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void multi_vec(const int v1[], const int v2[], int v3[], int n);
int comp_vec(const int v1[], const int v2[], int n);

int main(void) {
    int i, n, eq_check;

    printf("Enter the length of the vectors: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid length\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int v1[n], v2[n], v3[n];

    printf("Enter the first vector:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &v1[i]) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter the second vector:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &v2[i]) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    multi_vec(v1, v2, v3, n);

    printf("The multiplication of the vectors is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", v3[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    eq_check = comp_vec(v1, v2, n);
    if (eq_check == 0) {
        printf("The vectors are not the same\n");
    } else {
        printf("The vectors are the same\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void multi_vec(const int v1[], const int v2[], int v3[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v3[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];
    }
}

int comp_vec(const int v1[], const int v2[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (v1[i] != v2[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped clear it up for me. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

the declarations of the arrays, like `v1[n]` and `v2[n]` and `v3[]` must be declared AFTER the variable `n` has received a valid value.

the posted code is trying to declare those VLAs before knowing how big they must be.

On some related info:

for ease of readability and understanding, 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

variable names should indicate `usage` or `content` or better, both.

when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  (see the `man` page for `scanf()`)

Follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing some of that up for me. This is only the second thing I've ever done in C and my class really hasn't been all that helpful in explaining some of the more simple guidelines. It's much appreciated.